# Телеграмм бот и модуль requests

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, requests

Я сделал бота, который должен говорить информацию про персонажей star wars.

```
#import modules
import telebot
import requests
from django.http import response
#token
token = '6911144695:AAGhos7-Intqk4DC94ZuHeeZb9ZsjMYiGgI' 
#connect token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
#function for processing command /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi, I'm bot=helper about heroes of Star Wars!\n\nWrite a your hero name:", parse_mode='Markdown')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def starwars(message):
    str(message.text)
    url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?search=' + message.text
    response = requests.get(url)
    answer  = response.json()['results'][0]
    name = answer['name']
    mass = answer['mass']
    height = answer['height']
    hair_color = answer['hair_color']
    skin_color = answer['skin_color']
    eye_color = answer['eye_color']
    birth_year = answer['birth_year']
    gender = answer['gender']

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Name:",name)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Mass:",mass)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Height:",height)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hair color:",hair_color)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Skin color:",skin_color)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Eye color:",eye_color)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Birth year:",birth_year)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Gender:",gender)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #infinity bot cheking
    while True:
        #chek bot msg
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
        except Exception as e:
            print('ЭТОТ ЧЕЛ НЕ РУССКИЙ, ОСТАНОВИ ЕГО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

Тут не работают запросы, что можно сделать чтобы бот заработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно "отдаете" полученный ответ пользователю. В том виде, в котором вы передавали переменные воспринимаются как `parse_mode`, а не как часть строки. Вот так должно работать:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def starwars(message):
    str(message.text)
    url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?search=' + message.text
    response = requests.get(url)
    answer = response.json()['results'][0]
    name = answer['name']
    mass = answer['mass']
    height = answer['height']
    hair_color = answer['hair_color']
    skin_color = answer['skin_color']
    eye_color = answer['eye_color']
    birth_year = answer['birth_year']
    gender = answer['gender']

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Name: {name}\nMass: {mass}\nHeight: {height}\nHair color: {hair_color}\nSkin color: {skin_color}\nEye color: {eye_color}\nBirth year: {birth_year}\nGender: {gender}")
```

ну и желательно отдавать все одним сообщением, чтобы бот не "спамил"